# Convert .caf file into mp4 using react-native expo

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

Below, I'm stopping an active recording; Getting reference to the URI of the recording.
I would like to then convert the file into mp4 or mp3.

```
console.log('Stopping recording..');
await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
const recordingUri = recording.getURI();
console.log('Recording stopped and stored at URI', recordingUri);
```

Comment: CAF is audio format while MP4 is video format.  You should convert to a standard audio format like MP3 if that's the case.

Comment: Sure. I can also use mp3 but I need a solution to just convert caf to mp3 please

Comment: You can specify iOS to record to MP4 as it supports  audio also and you don't need conversion - https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/#recordingoptionsios

Comment: Apple not support MP3 as format for recording.

Comment: WOW! I think you've figured it, I'll iterate on it and confirm answer!